# Exibir um item foreach apenas uma vez (caso este item esteja dentro da condição if)

Tags: php, codeigniter

Olá!
Para um chat, estou querendo exibir a data da mensagem somente uma vez, sendo esta; na primeira mensagem somente.
Exemplo:

`ONTEM
Mensagem 1
Mensagem 2
Mensagem 3`

`HOJE
Mensagem 1
Mensagem 2
Mensagem 3`

Hoje, o que tenho está funcionando assim:

`ONTEM
Mensagem 1
 ONTEM
Mensagem 2
 ONTEM
Mensagem 3`

`HOJE
Mensagem 1
 HOJE
Mensagem 2
 HOJE
Mensagem 3`

Hoje estou utilizando o seguinte código:

```
<?php
$dt_cadastro = strtotime($linha['dt_cadastro']);
$hoje_inicio = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d'), date('Y'));
$hoje_fim = mktime(23, 59, 59, date('m'), date('d'), date('Y'));
$ontem_inicio = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d') - 1, date('Y'));
$ontem_fim = mktime(23, 59, 59, date('m'), date('d') - 1, date('Y'));
$anteontem_inicio = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d') - 2, date('Y'));
$anteontem_fim = mktime(23, 59, 59, date('m'), date('d') - 2, date('Y'));
?>
<?php if (($dt_cadastro >= $hoje_inicio) AND ($dt_cadastro <= $hoje_fim)): ?>
<span class="chat-data" style="position:absolute; left:45%; padding-bottom: 0px;">                                                                    
<span class=""><?= 'HOJE' ?></span>
</span>
<?php elseif (($dt_cadastro >= $ontem_inicio) AND ($dt_cadastro <= $ontem_fim)): ?>
<span class="chat-data" style="position:absolute; left:45%; padding-bottom: 0px;">
<span class=""><?= 'ONTEM' ?></span>
</span>
<?php elseif (($dt_cadastro >= $anteontem_inicio) AND ($dt_cadastro <=  anteontem_fim)):
?>
<span class="chat-data" style="position:absolute; left:45%; padding-bottom: 0px;">                                                                    
<span class=""><?= 'ANTEONTEM' ?></span>
</span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Isto está dentro de um foreach

```
<?php foreach ($historico as $linha):?><br>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

PS: Se houver outra alternativa para deixar o código mais limpo e menos repetitivo, gostaria que me ajudassem também, por favor.

Comment: Você não poderia quem sabe criar um array para cada dia? Dai quando o horário se encaixar na sua condição a informações é salva no array **Hoje**, por exemplo, e quando for exibir as mensagens tu escreve só uma vez a palavra **Hoje** e faz um loop para trazer todas as mensagens dentro desse array

Comment: @R.Santos, não faço idéia de como funcionaria.

Comment: Eu não tenho muito conhecimento de PHP @WagnerFilho, mas como você esta salvando o conteúdo dessas variáveis? Que tipo de variável é essa?

Comment: Se está se referindo as variáveis de data, não estou salvando, só estou utilizando a fim de comparações com a data que estou recebendo do banco de dados

Comment: Posta o conteúdo do array $historico na sua pergunta

Comment: @ClaydersonFerreira, não precisa. Foi solucionado da forma que o  Thiago Santos propôs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro declara uma variável auxiliar antes do *foreach*: `$hoje1 = 0;`. Depois tu muda assim que deve funcionar:

```
<?php if($hoje1 == 0) { $hoje1 = 1; ?><span class="">HOJE</span><?php } ?>
```

Faz o mesmo para ontem e anteontem.

(Mudei a palavra hoje para HTML)

Comment: Cara, show.. funcionou!!
Valeu!

Comment: `<?php if($hoje == 0) { $hoje = 1; ?><span style="position:absolute; left:45%; padding-bottom: 0px;" class="chat-data">HOJE</span><?php } ?>`